# Regex how to match a word without a character in it

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match something like `{anyWord}` but exclude anything that has an underscore at the beginning, like this: `{_doNotMatchThis}`?

Input:

```
hi there {matchPlease}{andThis}, just doing some regex {_notThis}
```

Desired matches:

```
{matchPlease}
{andThis}
```

Without that condition of excluding the starting `{_`, I know that this regex pattern works well: `\{\w+\}`

I've tried to modify that to be, `\{!_\w+\}`, basically saying, "match anything that starts with `{`, then has a word that does *not* start with `_`, then ends in `}`". Thanks.

Comment: try this: `/\{[^_]\w+\}/g`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
/\{([^_].*?)\}/
```

And per @Geo and @nhahtdh in the comments, if you want only words:

```
/\{([^_]\w*)\}/
```

Comment: This would exclude the first character of `{matchPlease}` and `{andThis}`, catching only `atchPlease` and `ndThis`

Comment: to only match *words* it could be `/\{[^_](\w+)\}/`

Comment: @MurifoX, you are correct in that the capture group would exclude the first char...  as a happy accident it appears the OP is not capturing anyway..., i modified my answer to include the _not \__ in the capture group

Comment: `\w*?` is not necessary. In fact, it will trigger unnecessary backtracking. Use `\w*`, since `\w` does not contain `}`